# Removing a plotted point in scatter plot - matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Following sample is a simplified version on  matplotlib scatterplot example provided on their website, and shows my attempt to remove a point from scatter plot

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable

# the random data
x = np.random.randn(2)
y = np.random.randn(2)


fig, axScatter = plt.subplots(figsize=(5.5,5.5))

# the scatter plot:
axScatter.scatter(x, y)
axScatter.set_aspect(1.)


np.delete(x,1)
np.delete(y,1)
axScatter.scatter(x, y)

plt.draw()
plt.show()
```

I could not figure out a way to remove a point from scatter plot after plotting, though if i use the same method i can plot a new point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update the data of the plotted artist.

Also `numpy.delete` returns a copy of the array with the item deleted, so calling `np.delete(x, 1)` doesn't modify the original `x`.  You'll need to use `x = np.delete(x, 1)` instead, if you want to delete the second item.

As a quick example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

x, y = np.random.random((2, 10))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
scat = ax.scatter(x, y, s=150)

# Show the figure, then remove one point every second.
fig.show()
for _ in range(10):
    time.sleep(1)
    xy = np.delete(scat.get_offsets(), 0, axis=0)
    scat.set_offsets(xy)
    plt.draw()
```

Comment: The issue with using this method is that it does not resize the scatter plot every time a new character is added/removed.

Comment: @Rishabh - If you'd like to rescale the axes, call `ax.autoscale()` every time you remove a point.

Comment: `autoscale()` doesn't seem to work, as tested in [this example](http://pastebin.com/Hhjf5E0M)